# Jetty internal failure occurs (500: Response header too large) when no errors in application service

Tags: jersey, jetty, dropwizard, squid

I'm using dropwizard framework in my service that using jetty as the http server.

Until today the service works fine.
Since I add squid as proxy server before Ngnix I have a weird issue.

The application logs seems like everything works fine but the client of my service got 500 in specific requests.
Only after changing jetty logs to DEBUG mode, I noticed they print error message in DEBUG mode. (Strange).

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundMessageContext - org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 500: Response header too large
java.io.IOException: org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 500: Response header too large
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:173)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:441)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter$NonCloseableOutputStreamWrapper.write(ResponseWriter.java:325)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:167)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.flushBuffer(CommittingOutputStream.java:307)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.commit(CommittingOutputStream.java:261)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.CommittingOutputStream.close(CommittingOutputStream.java:276)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.OutboundMessageContext.close(OutboundMessageContext.java:839)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerResponse.close(ContainerResponse.java:412)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:784)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:444)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:434)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:329)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
        at io.dropwizard.jetty.NonblockingServletHolder.handle(NonblockingServletHolder.java:49)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1689)
        at io.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:34)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676)
        at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.handle(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:50)
        at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.doFilter(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:44)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1174)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1106)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:240)
        at io.dropwizard.jetty.RoutingHandler.handle(RoutingHandler.java:51)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:396)
        at io.dropwizard.jetty.BiDiGzipHandler.handle(BiDiGzipHandler.java:68)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:253)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.http.BadMessageException: 500: Response header too large
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.generateResponse(HttpGenerator.java:414)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:690)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:224)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:521)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:692)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:746)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:179)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:163)
        ... 56 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.nio.BufferOverflowException: null
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:189)
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.put(ByteBuffer.java:859)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.putContentLength(HttpGenerator.java:873)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.generateHeaders(HttpGenerator.java:785)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpGenerator.generateResponse(HttpGenerator.java:399)
        ... 64 common frames omitted
```

I added my response header size in logs and it is 0.
In addition, this endpoint works 3 times and only on the 4th time it fail. Again - application return 200 but jetty insert this error.

```
2020-05-18 11:04:28.747 [dw-221 - POST ------- - DEBUG - org.glassfish.jersey.tracing.general - FINISHED Response status: 200/SUCCESSFUL|OK [ ---- ms]
```

When working that only squid **OR** Ngnix in the middle of the communication between the client and my service everything works well.
When working with squid **and** Ngnix in the middle so it fails.

Also, another important information is that the failure occurring when my service holds the connection ~45 seconds before returning the results. Seems that the Jetty error log regarding the Response header is wrong and something else with communication happens. Any ideas?

Comment: What is your Jetty side HttpConfiguration values for the various header sizes? (this is a configuration found attached to the ServerConnector).  You can find this out by dumping the server object after it has started - `Server.dumpStdErr()`, look for `HttpConfiguration` in the output

Comment: I added in dropwizard server configuration: maxRequestHeaderSize: 100000Kib and maxResponseHeaderSize: 100000Kib. I tested the same flow only with squid and only with Ngnix and both works well alone. This issue occurs only when squid send to Ngnix and arrived to my application. I will add it in my question

Comment: You might want to check what on earth you are adding to the response headers, that size header buffer points at something wrong.   Try to keep it under 64k total (when you upgrade to HTTP/2 you'll be thankful that you did)

Comment: Thanks, When disabling add headers in squid everything works. To my opinion it's not fail because of the header size. It failed because some of the header properties not valid when connection open so much time. Seems like the error log from Jetty is not accurate